# ubuntu 16.04 screen stays black after wake-up from "systemctl suspend"

Tags: systemctl

Starting Tuesday 3/23/21, hitting the power button causes the usual disk sounds that indicate wake-up but screen stays black.
Pressing F1 - F12, ESC, return, etc. have no effect.  I have been using systemctl suspend for years without this problem.
So far a forced reboot is my only workaround.
Machine: desktop with Intel DZ77GA-70K motherboard.
BIOS : Intel version: GAZ7711H.86A.0021.2012.0222.2054, 02/22/12
CPU: Intel Core(TM) i7-3770S CPU @ 3.10GHz
video: AMD Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
Ubuntu 16.04.7, linux-image-4.15.0-140-generic:amd64
I can show a couple entries in /var/log/apt for 3/23 and 3/24, if they're pertinent.
There is a suggestion relating to laptops to change /etc/default/grub line 11 from
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" to
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0"
but I don't know enough to do this without advice.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me too recently, and after some searching it might have been a video driver missing (use `software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4` to select the driver). What I did to fix this is that I installed xscreensaver, which seemed to clear up the issue. (The noveau modeset thing has something to do with the closed-source video drivers not being used in Ubuntu, as they cant distribute them legally in their OS)

Comment: Installing xscreensaver apparently didn't add any code, because the problem remains.  Actually running xscreenserver doesn't help either.  I hope somone can offer an effective solution,,,